# What does EtherScan's Transaction Visualizer do?

Tags: transactions, etherscan

Go to this transaction https://etherscan.io/tx/0x832ae39d3848055a4ecaf70b036d53e6063c07ee97cfff504474fc1d1b703934. Then click on the 'Tools & Utilities' link. I am trying to figure out what this visualizer is showing. It shows what appears to be money coming out of one account (the `from` account) and into three different other accounts, but I can't figure out why it's showing that.

Does anyone know what is being shown in the transaction visualizer on EtherScan?

Comment: I can't find it, is this still available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like an attempt to visually represent / track the downstream flow of transactions from one account to the next. In the example you asked about, the visualizer shows 3 transactions coming out of the initial account, and if you click on the little blue dot right before each of the three destination addresses, it will show you what further transactions flowed out of these addresses. It does not appear that the transactions listed for each address are comprehensive because when I entered the original "from" address in the search bar of etherscan, it had several more outgoing transactions than those represented in the visualizer.

Below is the visual of your example, after I clicked on the destination addresses.
I didn't click on everything, but just wanted to give you the idea.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I think I was confused because this display is linked to from a transaction. So I expected it was a representation of how further transactions followed out of the original transaction. It's how ether flowed out of accounts, which begs the question: why is it called the transaction viewer? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Can you clarify how you see the difference between "how further transactions followed out of the original transaction" and "how ether flowed out of accounts."  I'm not sure I understood your comment. If you click on the Ether amount that flowed out of the address, you will see all the details of the transaction.  Do you mean that it's strange to call this tool a transaction 'visualizer' when the visual representation only actually shows Ether amounts?

Comment: Yes. It's the name I think that confused me. The circular bubbles are accounts not transaction. It's just confusing